# Pandas functions every minute using python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the max and the min Niveau every hour using python I have an idea but it's not working like I want it give

**The code I wrote**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Cmaregraphe.csv', sep='[;\s]+', engine='python')
a=df['Niveau'].max()

'''print('max niveau est : ' , a, 'durant la date : ', b )'''
print(df. groupby('Heure').mean())
```

**My Cmaregraphe.csv**

Contain 10366 lines here just a caption of it

```
Date ; Hour; Niveau         
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:00:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:01:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:02:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:03:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:04:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:05:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:06:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:07:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.77        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:08:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:09:00;3.75        
02/01/2020;00:09:00;3.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
df.groupby(['Date','Hour'])['Niveau'].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

```
                        min     max
Date        Hour        
02/01/2020  00:00:00    3.75    3.77
            00:01:00    3.75    3.77
            00:02:00    3.75    3.77
            00:03:00    3.75    3.77
            00:04:00    3.75    3.77
            00:05:00    3.75    3.77
            00:06:00    3.75    3.77
            00:07:00    3.75    3.77
            00:08:00    3.75    3.77
            00:09:00    3.75    3.75
```

Comment: Omg you saved my life thank you so much here's a check for you thank you sir

Comment: if I add mean it's gonna be the average no?

Comment: yes. mean is average

Comment: do you know how I can combine the python code to my page web I need to do a button for the max when I click the max I can see what python shows me in the console

Comment: one way to accomplish it is to use the Flask framework . here is a link  https://pythonbasics.org/what-is-flask-python/   hope it helps

Comment: hello sir how I could implement it with this code if you know how ,check the website https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689904/how-i-could-combine-flask-with-pandas